# Having trouble with Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I am having trouble with the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

For this question..the equation $5x\equiv 3 \pmod6$ I found there is exactly one incongruent solution modulo $6$. But then I found 3 solutions modulo $6$?

Similarly, in this system

$$\begin{cases}
x\equiv3 \pmod4\\
x\equiv5 \pmod3
\end{cases}$$

I am having trouble determining how many solutions there are? I think there is only one solution modulo $12$, but I am not so sure right now.

Comment: What were your three solutions? $5$ is invertible $\pmod 6$ with inverse $5$, so $x \equiv 3 \pmod 6$.

Comment: Yea I realized I make a mistake and theres only one solution. But what about the system of congruences?

Comment: Thats what was given. So would there be no solution?

Comment: Of course it makes sense for $x$ to be congruent to $5$ (mod $3$). Equivalence modulo something is defined for any two integers on the left/right. There is no magic role played by the integers $0,1,2$ (mod $3$), other than convenience.

Comment: The system has exactly one solution modulo 12, and that is precisely an illustration of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. What is it that you are not so sure about?

Comment: What is an "incongruent solution"?

Answer (score 2):

In both cases there is exactly 1 solution.

Easiest way to solve the second system is:
$$
\begin{cases}
x \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \\
x \equiv 5 \pmod 3
\end{cases} \Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x = 3 + 4k \\
3 + 4k \equiv 5 \pmod 3
\end{cases}\Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x = 3 + 4k \\
k \equiv 2 \pmod 3
\end{cases}$$

$$ \Rightarrow\begin{cases}
x = 3 + 4k \\
k = 2 +3l
\end{cases} \Rightarrow
x = 3 + 4(2+3l) = 11 + 12l$$

So:
$$x \equiv -1 \pmod{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   x \equiv 3 \pmod 4\\
   x \equiv 5 \pmod 3
\end{align}

For really small number such as this, you don't need a lot of high-powered math to get a feel for what the solution should look like

$x \equiv 3 \pmod 4 
   \implies x \in 
   \{\dots, 3, 7, \color{red}{11}, 
            15, 19, \color{red}{23}, 
            27, 31, \color{red}{35}, 39, \dots\}$

$x \equiv 5 \pmod 3 
   \implies x \in 
   \{\dots, 2, 8, \color{red}{11}, 
            14, 17, 20, \color{red}{23}, 
            26, 29, 32, \color{red}{35}, 38  \dots\}$

You can see that $x \in \{\dots, 11, 23, 35, \dots\}$

Which doesn't prove but strongly suggests that $x \equiv 11 \pmod{12}$